# Mysteriously encoded SMSs from Ethiopia. Is it sinister?

Tags: sms

Thought i'd try my luck here as i've not yielded any results in my Googling. I have received numerous SMSs from +251 (Ethiopia) that look like the following. I'm not sure if its a strangely encoded language, or some type of exploit. It's being sent to an iOS device. Doesn't seem to impact it.

```
(yt7y4z<PΣPΠP*8r0z2PΠP¤g!XXYYYΘÆPΠP 6zr0Pa&Δztv4w3Pw::PΠP 6zr0Δb2x09z:y2Pa77:y76PΠPa&PΠΔ"ck¤*!Δ3vt34:Δr2x09z22P77Δztv2PΠΔztqu2:Δrw;w3y0r22Δrz2Δz7Δrr1yrp92P47Δqzy4wry9Pt6xp1:PΠP47är9zts0zt7w9Pq77z4wz2Pä4:4Pv:6z48v2Py:8x79:Δzrpv9PΠΔw7Δs:9:t29P0v29z9Δz7Δq2Py27:
```

Comment: Looks rather like some encoded data.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal Encoded data is often ASCII to minimize the possibility of decoding errors. But if you mean characterset by encoding, yes that could be possible, although I suspect it not to be

Comment: This could be an SMS virus exploiting bugs in olders phones' handling of Unicode characters. Probably not effective against any phone made this decade.